# Can we afford deleting not good quality answers?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, moderation

I really really love your passion but I think you didn't take everything into consideration.

You are stating wonderful rules for achieving a really good quality answers and questions. But they require a strong effort. 
What happen if people get bored from these?

**What would have happened if at the beginning of Stack Overflow if they would have stated that every answer should meet strong quality requirement.** 
You know.. there are upvotes and downotes. They can close questions but deleting it.. and deleting a valid answer.. mmm.. doesn't happen to "normal" answers on almost any section of SE.

**Are you sure we can really afford deleting valid medium quality answer?**

I fear you could be forgetting that **the guys who are answering are not payed for their work**. And if a guy who is not payed reads a comment like this: *"This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it will be removed."*
Try to guess which will be his feelings. Put immediately, right now, into his clothes. 
(It's not nice to receive orders right?)

**Want to have beautiful high quality response? Improve them by your own :-) 

(It's not nice to receive orders right? Then have a look to the comment I've put here over and tell me if it was nice )**

It's time demanding? Yes, It is. But if you start to threaten people who contributed to this community by saying: "I'm the landlord of the community we stated these rules, now improve your answer or I will delete it". I don't know it it will work. But **I fear a lot of answers could simply be lost. And for what? Can we really afford this? Will it really make this community more constructive? Or just in our dreams?**

Have a look at this answer: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/913/103

The question is really well done, and I simply know that was one right answer from my experience. Beyond Compare is a good software. I've written the answer and people (members of this community) find it useful. They upvoted. **You would like to improve it? It's wikified :-)**

**I really appreciate the intent of Izzy and I tried to go towards him** (even if I was really upset by reading his comment). But the point is another..

There is an interesting question with just two answers. My answer is also wikified.
You know that there aren't many good software for a specific purpose.
There is just **one** Resharper, **one** Photoshop, **one** Autocad, one 3D Studio Max. I mean that there are maybe 100 file comparer 5 of which are nice and then a lot of not mature software. My answer was good. Was constructive.

I'm wondering if it's really better for this community to hurt people contibuting and, at the same time, delete one answer appreciated by the community, useful (since it's one really good program), wikified. When there are just 2 answers... ?

I really appreciate your enthusiasm. But people want something that works, not an empty community with wonderful rules.. I think you are really dreamers if you start to delete medium quality answers.

Also have a look to the SE guidelines. They are really different and far away from yours guidelines: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/642/how-do-you-interpret-this-blog-article-about-guidelines-on-se?noredirect=1#comment1668_642

Comment: Please, can you explain the downvote?

Comment: "Voting is different on meta.

Like normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta allows members to vote on questions and answers. For most posts, votes reflect the perceived usefulness: well-written, well-reasoned, well-researched posts tend to get more attention and more upvotes. Highly-voted and frequently-linked posts may become part of the community-curated FAQ or codified as part of the site’s Help pages.

Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites,

Comment: Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works. On posts tagged feature-request, **voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change** rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself."

Comment: @Braiam: can I ask you why you don't share my opinion? Sometime here seems like a competition.. I would prefer a normal discussion between intelligent people. Do you understand what I mean? You are not scared that the way we are applying rules is so strict? The guidelines were speaking of flexibility.. but here I can't see it.. Do you believe it will be better for the community?

Comment: I honestly didn't read or voted your question, I just went for the TL;dr version of @Gilles answer, forgot that you ever asked and voted the answer. Past experiences indicates that when your post is more than 2 paragraph long I will be left with the sentiment of *"what the heck have just I read"* since most of the time you describe a problem in a **very** roundabout way. I've sit down to read some lengthy post in the past because I have an idea that will be easily understood, yours sadly doesn't inspire me to read them.

Comment: @Braiam: Thanks for answering.. I think I'm saying very interesting things in a very bad way.. I'm trying to improve on many stuff. SE is relative. One of the reason which lead me here is that I'm trying to express better, to have my personal growth. Probably a big mistake I do is "describe a problem in a very roundabout way".

Comment: "there is just one Resharper, one Photoshop, one Autocad, one 3D Studio Max" This is wrong on every count, I have used 2 other alternatives to Reshaper, 4 to Photoshop, I am are of atleast 3 for Autocad, and I've used an alternitive to 3D Max.
Please, when making your arguements do some basic research so you can give good examples. (It will only make it better to illustrate your point)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, we can afford to delete Low Quality Answers.
Stack Exchange Sites, solve problems by throwing Huge amounts of people at it.
Truly vast amounts of experience can be brought to bear on the problem.

Even now in our young stage, questions are getting dozens to hundreds of views,
very quickly.

- If we assume that 20% of views come there thinking "*I know the answer to the question*", and are ready to post there answer if someone has not already posted it.
- So with 3 dozen views being common, that is 7 people wanting to post an answer.
- Lets say there are 3 reasonable answers (Fairly high), that is 2-3 people per answer (Some people (our Experts) can answer multiple programs for each problem. I know I can for most that I can answer well.)
- That means at minimum there are **2-3 people wanting to post each answer.**
- Thus by definition we can afford to delete an answer, because the expertise that went to the post is *cheap*, we have more of it.
- But if they find the answer already there, they won't post. Even if their answer could be better.
- Thus we can't afford not to delete Low quality answers, if they are not going to be improved.

A better question is where should that bar be set?
How much time should someone be given to improve there answer?

Comment: Ok, then let's to the experiment. One of my medium quality answer was deleted. (I had also already edited it and improved the quality of it but Gilles didn't realized). Let's wait until someone will give the same answer in a better quality. I bet it will happen in one to three year. PS: I upvoted you because of this sentence: "But if they find the answer already there, they won't post. Even if there answer could be better."

Comment: I would prefer to read **good** answers not meaning that are **good** formatted, but that advice some **good** program. *I know you are about to bother me (:-p) saying good and best is opinionable, but between intelligent people it's not needed. You know what I mean and you also agree on that on this point.*

Comment: I was tempted to answer the question you did with BeyondCompare, but I didn't because you already had.
(Also because I assumed my knowledge of it was less than yours as Its been 3 years since i used it.)

Comment: then you know it's really a good program and that mine could be a really good advice. I had also improved my question (after Izzy asked for it) and it was also wikified!! Gilles deleted it..

Comment: @Sam: I don't care, about that post. I can't remember how good your post was. I just remember I was thinking the same tool. Thus illustrating my point that others will suggest the same thing. Thus that your post was deleted is a thing We as a community don't care about.

Comment: try to ask yourself the following question: "why do I prefer to look for the evidence to show the deletion of that answer was not so a bad thing and Sam wants to look at the evidence that show that beyond compare was a really valid answer?". Because human being want to find confirmation for what they believe to avoid put themself into discussion. This doesn't mean human being don't do mistake. The history is full of mistakes made by million of people. To avoid mistakes a strong effort is required.

Comment: You are making mountains out of mole hills, mate.
How about you write another answer for beyond compare, and post it. Make it better. Make it the best answer you can.
The perfect answer. Let it shine out as a light, for how good an answer can be. Make it beutiful, so that noone mistakenly deletes it. Make it detailed, so all can see your expertise. Make it clear, so that all can understand it. Show us this great tool, rather than complaining for hundreds of words on Meta.

Comment: the problem is that! I will not loose other time. I'm not payed for doing it, and my effort wasn't appreciated.. and this is the same reaction that most of people will have to error of cocky moderator. Howewer.. thanks for your time. I really hope to be wrong.

Comment: @Sam: Why do people come to our sites in the first place? Because there's high quality stuff here. There won't be high quality stuff if we don't filter out the low quality stuff first.

Answer (score 3):

We can't afford *not* deleting low quality answers.

When this site was established, Stack Exchange laid out some [ground rules](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules). Please read them. Read our [guidelines for quality answers](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality), as well.

Yes, writing a good answer takes effort. The reward is that the answers are useful. It's the fact that we produce good content that keeps people engaged.

You have received a lot of specific, polite advice regarding your contributions. You didn't receive “orders”. You know that Beyond Compare is a good fit for that question? Then explain how it is! Go through the list of requirements and show how they're met. You could have done that in the time it took you to write all these meta posts.

Your posts on the meta site show that you're willing to put a lot of effort into writing on subjects that you like. If you were willing to put as much effort into writing posts that are relevant to this site, you could be a good contributor. If you disagree with our [goal](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules) of building a high-quality site, you should stick to places that better matches your interests, such as [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/).

Comment: Wait just one second. Only for better understanding. Who is "Gilles"? Is one of the founder of SE community? I thought we were making the guidelines and this was the reason because meta was created. You are speaking from Guidelines can be improved. Also you are making a lot of confusion on some topic. Have a look to the foundamental guidelines of this community, to its goal and how to achieve them. They speaks of flexibility. http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/642/how-do-you-interpret-this-blog-article-about-guidelines-on-se

Comment: @Sam I've been using Stack Exchange for 4 years, and a moderator on several sites for 3. I'm familiar with the blog post you cited.

Comment: then why are you threating me like a child.. you deleted the post of beyond compare which was useful (I had modified it), put on hold one topic which intent was really clear while you should try to answer to that topic showing an effort. I'm making a strong effort here. You can share my opinions or not, but a moderator shouldn't, in my opinion, act as you are doing. I've been moderator on several sites and I was speaking with guys. I think it's clear that I'm trying to contribute. Take 1 minute of your like to think if you are only a snobbish cocky boy or something more than this.

Comment: I've also read the ground rules.. he speaks of deleting **very** poor quality answers (in a way which I don't like). But he also says: "Good answers on this site will be in the form of honest testimonials that share first hand experience with something and why it meets the needs of the asker.

You should answer questions when you have first hand knowledge of things that satisfies at least most of the constraints given in the question. You should be ready to talk about your experience with it, what you liked about it, what features it does have, within the context of the question."

Comment: And it also adds: "Answers that do not even come close to meeting the constraints described in the question should be flagged as not an answer, and will be removed quickly." - it's really different from saying: "we will close medium quality answer". Look at the question of mine which you have deleted.. I had already improved it.. are you sure it was worth to be deleted?