# Should this answer stick around and be considered as an answer? As per the sites ground rules?

Tags: discussion

Should [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1943/115) be considered as an answer and be allowed to stick around? Or should it be deleted?

The reason I ask is that it doesn't meet the all the requirements of the question.

i.e.:

- quirkiness of the digital production
- digital asset management

Comment: Related: [Blatantly wrong accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78438/blatantly-wrong-accepted-answer/78441#78441)

Answer (score 6):

I'll defend myself.

The [ground rules](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/455/1097) say:

> You should answer questions when you have first hand knowledge of things that satisfies *at least most of the constraints given in the question*. You should be ready to talk about your experience with it, what you liked about it, what features it does (or perhaps doesn't) have, within the context of the question. You should also talk about any potential quirks that you can think of, and even things that you found to be a down side of the product. In short, share your experience with something, not simply your knowledge that it exists.

I've presented Trello as a possible alternative project management tool.  I've talked a little about how it might fulfill *most* of your requirements, and highlighted the ways in which it falls short.  I've also added how you might work around those limitations should you find the other strengths of Trello worthwhile.

In short, I believe the answer is fully in line with the ground rules.

Remember that answers *aren't just for you*.  While you might think that a particular tool doesn't suit your needs **exactly**, someone else with similar needs might come along, see your question, and find that the answer does suit them quite well.

Additionally, if you think an answer is inadequate, it's much more constructive to add a comment saying *why* and adding more insight that might allow the answerer to update the answer, address your concerns, and add more information.

Jumping straight to deletion is a fantastic way to scare people away from the site completely.

Comment: No, no. Don't get me wrong. I was just asking, not recommending anything. The only reason I asked it here was that it's better to have a discussion. And since I myself am not so aware of the ground rules so I asked a question here. And for the very same reason I didn't flag or DV it. Discussing at meta's healthy specially when all eyes are on this site. Thank-you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 4):

Incorrect answers are not subject to deletion. If you feel the answer isn't a proper fit to the question, the correct course of action is to downvote and move on. This is exactly what the voting system exists to be used for.