# What are our canned comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Now we are public, that means a bit more traffic and lots of people asking and answering. Which leads to the boredom of having to write a comment each time something is wrong with a post. So, do we have some canned comments for both questions and answers?

Answer (score 9):

#### The easy way to comment

The [AutoReviewComments user script](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/3583) provides a handy way to keep a collection of template comments on hand. I (Izzy) modified this script with some features to handle site-specific comment templates. My version is published [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/IzzySoft/9206717) (though it includes my custom comments as the default, it shouldn't overwrite yours as long as you don't use the "reset" link: customizations you do are stored in your browser's "localStorage").

Later Caleb [re-factored the code](https://stackapps.com/a/4564/3583) from my gist against the original and kept just the code changes without changing the default comments. You can [see that code here](https://github.com/alerque/SE-AutoReviewComments) or install as [a user-script from here](https://github.com/alerque/SE-AutoReviewComments/raw/master/autoreviewcomments.user.js).

Once installed, you can use the import/export link to view the saved comment templates and mix and match from any of the following sources. Once you have the above mentioned script in place:

- If you simply want to replace your current settings, simply copy/paste the "preformatted text" to its import/export window, and click the "save" link. Done.
- If you want to merge, you will have to do that manually: open import/export, and edit there. This way you could e.g. simply copy/paste new/additional messages from here. Beware: Make sure to have the format consistent. These comments are formatted for the customized version of the script and must include the site url line. This format does not mix and match with the original script. If you use that, remove all the lines containing `§§§`.

#### Shared default comments

- Izzy's stock comments specific to this site below (or [full gist](https://gist.github.com/IzzySoft/58ba94af51720ef8adeb), [text](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/IzzySoft/58ba94af51720ef8adeb/raw/988de50e4edc5f3183ef22b0183ad44652bcb6fb/AutoReview+DefaultComments); has all my sites, might be updated from time to time at these locations):

  ```
  ###[Q]Low question quality
  §§§softwarerecs.stackexchange.com
  We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/$MYUSERID$) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

  ###[Q]Requirements unclear (formatting)
  §§§softwarerecs.stackexchange.com
  Though your description holds several criteria required to recommend matching software, it suffers some formatting issues to make them clearly stand out. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/$MYUSERID$) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. This will significantly improve your chances of good answers!

  ###[A]Low quality answer
  §§§softwarerecs.stackexchange.com
  This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/$MYUSERID$) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed.
  ```
- Caleb's stock comments for this site ([gist](https://gist.github.com/alerque/362a6aff9d98cb774801), [text](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alerque/362a6aff9d98cb774801/raw/e78e82d16f0c88a09c118ce3d723603734bc0da8/softwarerecs.se+comments)).
- *If you modify these or add more to your config, please add them here!*

#### Tips for writing your own

Each "full can" consists of 3 lines:

- First line starts with `###` and holds the title for orientation. Starting with an (optional) `[Q]` or `[A]` marks this comment to only show up for comments on questions resp. answers. Omitting this optional element makes the comment show up for both.
- Second line starts with `§§§` and optionally holds a site the comment is restricted to.
- 3rd line is the comment itself.

Some placeholders can be used and get replaced *by the script* with the corresponding values *when posting*:

- `$SITENAME$` / `$SITEURL` get replaced e.g. with "Software Recommendations" / "softwarerecs.stackexchange.com"
- `$MYUSERID$` gets replaced with *your* userID on the current site (so if you give helpful links, you might be rewarded with badges :)

[image: on questions] [image: on answers]
<sup>Screenshots: on questions / on answers (click images for full-size variants)</sup>

#### Tips for sharing

You can always use the Export/Import feature to share your customizations with others. You could e.g. use your own Gist for that, or a pastebin. Or copy/paste single comments from/to answers here. Just keep in mind that there's no merge functionality (yet).

You also can try the "external source" feature of the script to point to e.g. a maintained Gist "store". Careful with this, though, as I've not yet tested that (reports welcome – ping me e.g. in chat).

Answer (score 2):

This recommendation does not contain enough information to fulfil the requirements set out in the question and therefore does not meet our minimum quality requirements. For guidelines on what your recommendation should contain please see [What is required for an answer to be high quality?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality)

Possibly with the addition of:

If your answer is not improved it will shortly be removed.