# What is required for a "there is no such program" answer to be high quality?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, policy

[What is required for an answer to be high quality?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/903) does a good job to explain what is expected for answer pointing to a program.

What is required for a "there is no such program" answer to be high quality?

Comment: Related (not duplicate): [Impossible/impractical requests?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/696/60)

Comment: For further reference: Here is an [example](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/18088/94) of such an answer.

Answer (score 15):

To give such an answer, either you must be pretty profient in that area to be sure – or the question must be a "little stupid". In both cases, an answer should not be limited to "there is no such program" – but should give proof/reasons why. Depending on the question, such reasons could include

- technical impossibilities (such a program cannot be written for these technical reasons)
- some of your background, explaining what makes you sure there is not/cannot-be such a program
- a link to such reasoning, or a study, giving proof

Just to say "I never heard of" is far from being enough; it doesn't even say you've searched for it, or know what the OP is talking about ;)

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, if there is no such software then you shouldn't answer. In the future, such software may exist and the question will then be answered.

If the question itself is stupid, is way too specific or asks for something technically impossible, it should just be closed.