# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, specific-answer, deleted-answers

My [answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/26567/1935) was deleted and I'm not sure why. The question asked for

- "stealth keylogger", where stealth was defined as "does not appear in the Task Manager"
- "works well on Windows 10", also [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [windows-10](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10)
- "either a closed or open source"

No other requirements.

My answer says

- "The list on keyloggers.com lists the following keyloggers with the property 'Hidden in Task Manager'", thus matching the stealth requirement
- "All of them are advertised for Windows 10", matching the Windows 10 requirement
- "either a closed or open source" - well, hard to not fulfill that

Ok, we have a [standard defined here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality), so let's see how I do:

I have covered each requirement, named and linked the products, I have mentioned the price, I have even covered anything else that might be important for the OP ("trial version").

I have not simply copy/pasted a list I found on the internet. I filtered it and visited each of the vendors websites, to see if the Windows 10 requirement matches, since the list was a bit old.

So really, I don't know why it was deleted. If someone could please elaborate.

Comment: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/asking-questions-about-potentially-bad-software related.

Comment: I think the problem with those answers is that its a simple list. We don't know what research you have done, or what option is better than the other. In short, why should the user pick one option over the other?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: for testing an anti-keylogger, a list of items is better than a single product. OP certainly wants to know whether his anti-keylogger works for all the products.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Deleting the answer was not necessary for this particular answer, because

1. the products are only used for testing purposes, not for real use. In this case, there is no competing requirement that would prefer one of the products over the other such as price, usability etc.
2. in case of doing system tests, a list of products is preferred over a single suggestion, so the answer is exactly what OP wants.
3. downvoting would have been enough. This would give the OP the chance to decide for himself whether this answer was not helpful, helpful or even acceptable as the answer.
4. deleting the answer is probably a hammer criterion on Software Recommendations, given it needs 5 users to vote for undeletion if the answer was edited. There are only 15 such users on SR, so 33% of them need to vote for undeletion, which is unlikely.
5. deletion by a moderator is even worse, since it cannot be undeleted.
6. It is really demotivating. A comment would have been nice, deleting after some days of inactivity as a follow-up action.
7. As listed in the question, it follows most of the requirements for a good answer, except the personal use. This makes it better than many answers on SR. So why should exactly this one be deleted?

Answer (score 4):

You need to have personal experience with software that you recommend, as per the [answer quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/46). Your answer essentially falls in the 'I Googled your query and found this' section as of right now - even if you filtered them manually.

You should at least comment on everything you recommend - even "this works great" is enough in my book.

[Journeyman is right](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/why-was-this-answer-deleted#comment4253_2359):

> I think the problem with those answers is that its a simple list. We don't know what research you have done, or what option is better than the other. In short, why should the user pick one option over the other?

Comment: For testing an anti-keylogger, a list of items is better than a single product. OP certainly wants to know whether his anti-keylogger works for all the products