# Moderator deleted the only answer I would accept

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, deleted-answers

A moderator deleted my answer here:

[Free software to track movies I'm watching](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/free-software-to-track-movies-im-watching)

My answer might not be the most comprehensive, but it works for all my needs. I might accept a better answer in the future, but currently only 1 other person has submitted an answer, and I definitely am not accepting his in its current state.

I edited my answer into the question so that people could see it. I feel what the moderator did was wrong by deleting the accepted answer and it should be restored.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is what on SE sites is called "link only". As the moderator pointed out, we've got some [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) here. If you read them, and incorporate some improvements with your answer, it can be undeleted. Just flag it for moderator attention when done.

Comment: While my answer might not be acceptable per the rules, as the question asker I am in a unique position to say that yes, it is acceptable to me. There should be some kind of exception in this case, as any explanations I add is just explaining to myself something I already know

Comment: If you already know, you probably also know the answer as it was (so why post it at all?) :) But that's not the point: The answer is not just for you, but also for others who might be after the same thing. And they might need the additional details.