# "Put on hold because opinion-based" in SE Software Recommendations

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

A question I made just got put on hold because it's too "opinion-based".

If I understand correctly what "SE Software Recommendations" is, it's a place where people **recommend** software, based on the question.

The sole word **recommend** implies an opinion.

- *I recommend you `Software A` because...*
- *I'd rather use `Software B` because...*
- *etc...*

Therefore I can't really understand why my question was put on hold because of being `opinion-based`, neither I understand why that is even an option in SE Software Recommendations.

Comment: Are you referring to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/27945/46?

Comment: @Undo Yes. That is the question I'm referring to.

Comment: Ah, "I recommend you Software A because..." & "I'd rather use Software B because..." are for Answers, not Questions

Comment: @Tom that's the answer to Alexander's question here :) // Alexander: With "the ultimate" (cause for this) being removed by the latest edit, it's still a bit broad (as Caleb pointed out there).

Answer (score 4):

The word “recommend” does *not* imply an opinion. Furthermore, while answers might be somewhat opinion-based (but no more than on other Stack Exchange sites), they are not supposed to be **primarily** opinion-based. The close reason isn't “opinion-based”, it's “primarily opinion-based”.

Here, like on other Stack Exchange sites, we focus on solving problems. “You should use this software because …” isn't more opinion-based than “you should use this code because …” (a typical kind of answer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)). In fact, in a way, we put more emphasis on the *because* — we [require that answers explain how the recommended product fits the requirements and the user story in the question](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality).

Regarding [your question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27945/searching-for-full-stack-web-development-boilerplate), I recommend that you read our [question guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) as well. A good question has two elements: some precise requirements and a user story. Requirements are basically here to rule out products that just won't do, and can be checked mechanically against a feature matrix. The user story is a matter of fitting a concrete purpose; while this does involve judgement, this judgement should be backed up by an analysis, not based on opinion. Once again, it isn't “use this”, but “use this **because**…”.

The relative importance of the requirements and the user story varies.In your case, the requirements are fairly generic; they're things that I expect many major web development frameworks to have. How would you choose between them? “THE ultimate” is not a criterion.

There's probably a good question lurking here, but you need to help us help you. Edit your question to describe your user story. Some tips:

- What kind of project do you want to focus on?
- When you take out the parts you don't want to bother with, what's left?
- You seem to be dissatisfied with frameworks that don't let you focus on the parts you like, what is missing in those frameworks?
- Why don't you want Symfony?