# Should we link to the quality guideline from the how-to-ask section?

Tags: feature-request, tour-page, new-users

We have the [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) question. It is linked from the [Tour](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour).

Honestly, I never read the tour, except scrolling to the end to get the [informed] badge. I never expected important information to live there. Once familiar with one site of the SE network, reading the tour was becoming boring.

Instead, I rather go to the [Help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) because it has much more details.

However, the mentioned wealth of information is not referred to, e.g. I expected to find above link in [How do I ask a good question?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Could we please have a hyperlink there?

Edit:

I found out that it is linked from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but he Meta post is not much about the topic but about the content.

Comment: I just checked: Afraid the "How do I ask a good question" page cannot be edited by mods (AFAIK the only one we can customize ourselves is [What topics can I ask about here?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Ok. Didn't know the moderators were restricted.

Comment: Yepp, we are. There are always "higher forces" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that were possible (reading the comments), then Yes. This, however, may be not possible as looking at some of the other StackExchange sites, each Help Center is exactly the same. This may be something where if content is to be added to the Help Center, it has to pass through [Stack Exchange's Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

If it is possible, I agree that this would be a great addition. I don't think removing the guidelines from the Tour should occur (whether you read it or not, it still should be there for those who do). I think (again, if possible), we should add:

- [Question Quality Guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)
- [Answer Quality Guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality)

as both are needed to create the best possible questions/answers for this site.

Answer (score 2):

I'm told this is possible. We just need to come up with exactly what we want changed.

I propose adding this line to the top of the page, just under the "How do I ask a good question" heading:

> This site enforces stricter quality requirements than most. Please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for details on what we require.