# How to escalate or request another moderator's review on a deleted answer?

Tags: feature-request

Assume a moderator deletes one of my answers by mistake (Assume moderator agreed he failed to read the question and my answer properly), is there a way to request for another moderator's review or request to un-delete the answer with proper reasons ?

Comment: +1 I would also like other moderators to give their opinions. Unfortunately one is on vacation and the other has not been as active as usual this week. I am sure they will show up soon though! :-)

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul, Oh that could be another reason the active moderator sometime tries to "read too fast" to cover as many items as possible :-), this feature request will help to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: While waiting, I suggest you re-read https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/387/140 that will help you write great answers.

Comment: One of us is always in chat (I usually am, unless I'm on vacation) where you can "ping" us. And to not look "offensive", there're always nice ways to phrase things, like "I don't understand why my post was deleted, can you please look and explain what's wrong with it" :) (I've just checked which one you could mean – and I guess [I could answer that](/help/promotion))

Comment: @NicolasRaoul when in doubt, enter our mod room and `@@` all of your collegues. I'm sometimes a bit busy, but usually react on pings as soon as I see them in my inbox.

Comment: @lzzy FYI I am talking about a case where "moderator agreed he failed to read the question and my answer properly", please suggest a way to open a feature request to handle such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Summing up from the comments, adn adding some details:

We moderators ar "common people" like you – so we also sometimes make mistakes. Also, from time to time we might disagree on how to handle a situation – or what to do with a certain post. That is why I wrote that, in such a situation, you can:

- **flag the relevant post as "needs moderator attention"** and explain your concerns in the comments. This is the most modest way, as only moderators can see this.
- if you think there's no "secrecy" needed, you can **bring it up in chat.** One of us mods is usually there, so you can even `@ping` us. Phrase your concern politely (I'm certain you will do – but I write this explicitly for the benefit of others ), and we will take care of it.

Once it's brought to our attention, we moderators have ways to discuss that amongst ourselfs, and come to a conclusion. That might be "all is as it should be", or "some action is necessary" – none of us is stubborn and insists on his position, we always work as a team.

That also covers the special case where "moderator agreed he failed to read the question and my answer properly". Usually, in such a case the affected moderator corrects his mistake or consults his collegues for advice when in doubt – but sometimes the advice is on vacation or otherwise absent, and the issue will need some more time to be solved.

Not to forget: we also listen to advice from you. You know, we're humans – and to err is to be human (though some are more human than others). We stand corrected if we were wrong.

Comment: @lzzy, let me clarify what happened in this case, so you will understand as a real moderator/leader from point of my view also.

Comment: @lzzy, let me clarify what happened in this case...One fine morning almost all my answers (about 10) were deleted by a specific moderator even without giving me a chance to respond. I flagged two of my deleted posts with my reasons, for which the moderator deleted the original comment and updated the comment saying he "read too fast" before deleting that post, now he wants me to update the answer with few other screenshots, My request now is another moderator review all such deleted posts and help to create a new feature request to help other humans from these kind of situation.

Comment: @Bruce I'm just walking through your deleted posts, and I agree with … the mod who kept them deleted. They lack details – and they lack disclosure (the apps you recommended are written by you, aren't they? At least in one post you say so). Please take a look at [our discussion on answer quality](/q/356/185). Is there any answer that is not self-promotion? Also check [our corresponding help center document](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) on that topic. As it currently stands, I see none I'd undelete, sorry.

Comment: @lzzy, Good team work, keep it up! FYI the recommended softwares in my answers were mine however happy to see you agree that if i add another answer that is not of my own software, you would undelete all answers :-) , Anyway Thanks for your time.

Comment: I see the humor in your comment, Bruce. I agree in so far that we could undelete *some* of them then if they are updated accordingly ;)